# Using actual branch head revision number in Hudson

Tags: python, svn, jenkins, hudson

We have multiple branches in SVN and use Hudson CI jobs to maintain our builds. We use SVN revision number as part of our application version number. The issue is when a Hudson job check out HEAD of a brach, it is getting HEAD number of SVN not last committed revision of that brach. I know, SVN maintains revision numbers globally, but we want to reflect last committed number of particular brach in our version.

is there a way to get last committed revision number of a brach using python script so that I can checkout that branch using that revision number?
or better if there a way to do it in Hudson itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the last committed revision of a path using python:

```
from subprocess import check_output as run # >=2.7

path = './'
cmd = ['svn', '--username', XXXX, '--password', XXXX, '--non-interactive', 'info', path]
out = run(cmd).splitlines()
out = (i.split(':', 1) for i in out if i)
info = {k:v.strip() for k,v in out}

# you can access  the other svn info fields in a similar manner
rev = info['Last Changed Rev']

with open('.last-svn-commit', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(rev)
```

I don't think the subversion scm plugin can give you the information you need (it exports `SVN_URL` and `SVN_REVISION` only). Keep in mind that there is no difference between checking out the 'Last changed Rev' and the HEAD revision - they both refer to the same content in your branch.

You might want to consider using a new job for every branch you have. This way, the commit that triggers a build will be the 'Last changed Rev' (unless you trigger it yourself). You can do this manually by cloning the trunk job and changing the repository url, or you could use a tool like [jenkins-autojobs](http://pythonhosted.org/jenkins-autojobs/) to do it automatically.

Comment: gvalkov,
The svn info command is failing on authentication! Is there a way to supply creds with this?
And also, I tried to use pysvn module(it got callback for creds) but unable to get last committed info of my branch.
BTW, this python script will execute in the different brach, not in the working directory of branch that I tried to get revision info.
Thanks

Comment: Hey, @user1366786, I've update the answer. It really looks to me that the job-per-branch approach might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks gvalkov. It worked.
Yes, we are using different job per branch and also triggers. We had this issue because our jobs are svn revision number parameterized with default HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Except `svn info` you can also use `svn log -q -l 1 URL` or `svn ls -v --depth empty URL`